# How to enable tokens for custom entity?

Tags: entities, 8, tokens

I had the impression that in Drupal 8 all entity tokens are provided automatically since it uses the new field structure but I don't see anything available for my entity.

Do I need to enable something in the annotation or did I get it wrong and tokens have to be provided manually like in D7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had the impression that in Drupal 8 all entity tokens are provided
>   automatically since it uses the new field structure but I don't see
>   anything available for my entity.

That impression is wrong. Drupal (core) doesn't provide any generic tokens for entities, all that are in core are hardcoded.

Now, token.module, just like in D7, provides some tokens for *configurable* fields. Simply because the existing functionality was ported to D8. It is possible to extend that to all fields and it shouldn't even be that hard. In fact, there's an explicit check that ignores anythig that's not a configurable field, so we just have to remove that and see what happens.

Comment: Well, this is a bit disappointing.

Comment: @Berdir, is there an issue to make that happen?

Comment: That happend a long time ago, this is an old answer:) It however only happens if the entity type/token type is not already defined.